# How do I create a production build/minified scripts for Sencha Touch app?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

There doesn't seem to be documentation on how to build a production mode app for ST2 using Sencha Cmd utility on their web site anywhere.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference in command to build your app between SDK Tools and Sencha Cmd:

To build your app for testing:

```
sencha app build testing
```

To build your app for production deployment:

```
sencha app build production
```

To package your application for distribution on App Stores:

```
sencha app build native
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Whereabouts on their site is this info?  Also, do you know if there is a way to do skip the sass/css part as this is causing me errors and not sure how to fix?

Comment: Seem like these infos are missing in the docs, so I can only tell you that it's just my personal experiences with Sencha Cmd. For your second question, I never encounter the same problem before but you can try remove css part in app.json which used for sencha cmd to build your app.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the building documentation but which seems to be outdated: 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/guide/building

@Eli is it still necessary to create the JSB file first which checks which classes are needed? In the Sencha Doc it says thats needed and should be done like this:

```
sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3
```

and then the the app will be built from it:

```
sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d ./
```

Does anyone know whether the JSB-step is necessary? I'm on Sencha Touch 2.2.0

Comment: I'm testing those things for extjs, not touch, and it looks that there's no other way than creating the jsb file. Look this http://www.akawebdesign.com/2011/11/17/sencha-sdk-tools-jsbuilder/ and this http://deaneturner.com/blog/2011/11/12/using-jsbuilder3/.

Comment: Do not use 2.2 for building.  It is extremely buggy. I upgraded to 2.3 and all the problems went away.

Comment: FYI: This is how things were done in ExtJS 3 and whatever version Touch was on then.